# How to update this classic Swift line to a more recent Swift (compatible with Xcode 12 and iOS 14) properly?

Tags: ios, swift

How to update this classic Swift line to a more recent Swift (compatible with Xcode 12 and iOS 14) properly?:

`var sceneData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: path, length: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, freeWhenDone: true)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this was ever legal Swift. It seems to be mixing parameters from `init(bytesNoCopy:...)` and `init(contentsOfFile:...)` which do different things. (And no method is going to take DataReadingMappedIfSafe as a value for length). What operation do you expect this to do?

Comment: Ah, it is from an open source app I downloaded so maybe it didn't actually compile in the first place. I updated this, so I can answer and close this question as answered.

Comment: Looking at all of that, it seems really weird. Hope the tutorial maker wasn't purposely messing with people downloading the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trudged through and found a way, so answering the question:

```
extension SKNode {
            class func unarchiveFromFile(_ file : String) -> SKNode? {
                if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: "sks") {
                    do {
                        var sceneData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: url.absoluteString, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
                        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: sceneData as Data)

                        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
                        let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
                        archiver.finishDecoding()
                        return scene
                    } catch {
                        return nil
                    }
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Data` also has `init(contentsOfFile:options:)`, so you can use that directly rather than having to call `as Data` later.

Comment: Thanks for notifying!